# Change Flash security whilst offline

Tags: flash, security, cross-domain, cd

I've got Flash content that needs to run within a web page off a CD. It works fine if I change the security settings in the Flash Global Security settings screen but that can only be accessed online. So...

1. Can the security violation be overcome with a cross-domain XML on the local drive somehow?
2. Can the Global Security settings screen be displayed without an internet connection?
3. Can the security settings be changed without using the Global Security settings screen

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need create a text file with suffix `.cfg` at the following location:

```
%appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#Security\FlashPlayerTrust
```

on each new line, add the folder in which the .swf file lives, so the contents of `myTrustFile.cfg` might be:

```
d:\flashContent
```

This will give the content elevated local trust. On non-windows boxes, it may be worth doing a web search for the term `flashplayertrust`. There's plenty of prior art.

Answer (score 0):

spender beat me to it :P

But I would also add if this is to be distributed across many Windows PCs, you can add a Batch file on the CD itself that would auto-write this new entry to the trust-file (on a simple double-click of the file :D).

I'm not nearly familiar enough with Batch syntax to whip-up an example though! Just something that might be worth searching for online.

Comment: Indeed. AppleScript for those on the dark side too. Cheers